# CSS Keyframes animation disappearing after complete

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

My animation keeps disappearing after it completes its animation. I have followed the answers to other questions but it still doesn't help. My CSS is as follows:

```css
.upvote-object {
    width: 50px;
    height: 62.5px;
    background: url('/icons/upvote.png') left center no-repeat;
    background-size: 50px 62.5px;

    &.upvoted {
        background: url('/icons/upvoted.png') left center no-repeat;
        background-size: 50px 62.5px !important;
    }
}
.ani-upvote {
    background: url('/icons/upvote-sprite.png') left center no-repeat;
    background-size: 1700px 62.5px;

    animation: play 3s steps(34);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% {
        background-position: -1700px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    100% {
        background-position: -1700px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I am calling it in my HTML like this:

```
<div class="upvote-object ani-upvote"></div>
```

Here's the problem: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Joshie/24ab3a9u/)

**UPDATE:** Please also know that the animation must also stay on the last frame! (Green)

Comment: Add working snippets or a JSFiddle please?

Comment: @RhapX kk just added a Fiddle that has the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. But I’m not a CSS expert. So I’m sorry for not being able to explain why it works. Maybe you know why :)

```css
    .upvote-object {
        width: 50px;
        height: 62.5px;
        background: url('http://sstaging-parts.herokuapp.com/icons/upvote.png') left center no-repeat;
        background-size: 50px 62.5px;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .ani-upvote {
        background: url('http://staging-parts.herokuapp.com/icons/upvote-sprite.png') left center no-repeat;
        background-size: 1700px 62.5px;

        animation: play 2s steps(33); // changed the steps to 33
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    @keyframes play {
        100% { background-position: -1650px; opacity: 1; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes play {
        100% { background-position: -1650px; opacity: 1; } // Changed the position to -1650
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I got it to work. I think it has to do with the sprite and the position where it stops the animation... if that makes any sense.

Comment: @JLF Ah I see... I'll see what I can do

Comment: Fixed it on the Fiddle. Unfortunately, this is irrelevant to the problem because I had to add the direct remote link to the fiddle for it to link properly. It works in the real setup. This is also the beginning icon, it should be staying on the last frame of the other class `.ani-upvote`.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: @JLF No problem, it was fun trying to figure it out :)